# How to tell when MKMapView and visible MKAnnotationView are finished drawing?

Tags: iphone, rendering, mkmapview

I'm displaying a MKMapView with MKAnnotations some of which are selected and showing their Annotation.
I am trying to grab an image of the displayed map and annotations using the -renderInContext.

90% of the time the Map, MKPinAnnotationView's and selected annotations are correctly captured.
The other 10% of the time the image is missing something, usually the MKPinAnnotationViews or their annotations if selected.

I've added code to deal with the Map itself loading it's map data.

But I haven't been able to track down something that would indicate to me that all of the visible MKPinAnnotationView's have been drawn
and if selected their annotations displayed??

the closest hint I've come across is the addObserver, although I haven't figured out what could be observed that would tell me when all of the drawing is done.

Thoughts?

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar problem, but the other half of it - how do you know when the map has finished loading the map data? (mapViewDidFinishLoadingMap doesn't fire when tiles are cached). You said you added code to deal with that - what does that look like?

Comment: I have same problem of detecting loading of google tiles. @Jeremy have you found solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I'm an idiot...
I finally tracked down the problem. In my viewForAnnotation routine in the MKMapView Delegate protocol I wasn't correctly setting values for reused MKPinAnnotationView's.
So some of the time I would reuse a view that had .canShowCallout set to YES and other times I'd reuse a view that had .canShowCallout set to NO.

> .<

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [MKMapViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKMapViewDelegate_Protocol/MKMapViewDelegate/MKMapViewDelegate.html) didAddAnnotationViews method.

If in that method, the drawing is still not ready for your requirements, you could then in there call your capturing method with performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:.

Comment: I was actually already using that method, and I still can't get consistent results.  Regardless of the time I allow I can't guarantee the Annotation will be displayed.  I'm checking everything I can window superview selectedAnnotations they all suggest the annotation is valid and displayed, but it isn't (at least not consistently).  One hint is this only seems to be inconsistent when I have more than one annotation displayed on the map at a time.??

Comment: Maybe if you posted some snippet of code that duplicates the problem or the addAnnotation and capture methods, something might pop out.